# League of Legends: Dominion center map buff (Storm Shield)

Tags: league-of-legends

I played Dominion yesterday for the first time, and I noticed that in the center of map there are two buffs (a flashing icon on the mini-map), one for each team.

What are the bonuses granted by these buffs? And what are their respawn times?

Comment: Personal shield + DOT on attacks is all the information I have found for the moment. Still don't know how long it lasts nor its respawn time.

Comment: I counted 3 minutes for respawn time of the central buff!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, I pulled these up with a LoL Replay of a Dominion game.

**Bonuses Granted**:

The character model grows by roughly x2

[image: Storm Shield]

The first grants an absorption shield with 212.5 (+12.5 x level) health that will recharge if the champion doesn't receive damage after 10 seconds.

[image: Lightning]

The second buff allows the champion to passively detonate a lightning blast inflicting 90 (10 x level) magic damage on the champion's autoattacks and damaging spells with a 4 second cooldown.
**Spawn Time**: 3:00 Minutes

**Channel Time**: 5 seconds

**Respawn Time**: 3:00 Minutes

**Duration**: ~45-60 Seconds (Not positive on this one, hard to find a game where someone kept it the whole time.)

Source: [League of Legends Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Storm_Shield)